# How to hide autogenarated Delete and Edit button In asp.net gridview for user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, autogeneratecolumn

I want to hide delete edit buttons from the customer role, but admin can see them. My Gridview has set autogenarated column = true.

Here is what I did:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdview" OnRowCreated="grdview_RowCreated" OnRowDataBound="grdview_RowDataBound" CssClass="table table-hover table-responsive" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceNo" HeaderText="InvoiceNo" SortExpression="InvoiceNo" NullDisplayText="Null" >
            <ControlStyle CssClass="form-control" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="InvoiceDate" SortExpression="InvoiceDate">
            <EditItemTemplate >
                <div class=" input-group">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdate2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Bind("InvoiceDate") %>'></asp:TextBox> 
                    <span class="input-group-addon">        
                        <a class=" glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" id="cal2"></a>
                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" PopupButtonID="cal2" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtdate2" runat="server"></asp:CalendarExtender>
                    </span>
                 </div>
              </EditItemTemplate>
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("InvoiceDate") %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
              <HeaderStyle Width="200px" />
              <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="Amount" >
              <ControlStyle CssClass="form-control" />
          </asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Items" HeaderText="Items" SortExpression="Items" >
              <ControlStyle CssClass="form-control" />
          </asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="category" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="category" Visible="False" >
              <ControlStyle CssClass="form-control" />
          </asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="description" Visible="False" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="qty" HeaderText="Qty" SortExpression="qty" >
              <ControlStyle CssClass="form-control" />
          </asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="remarks" HeaderText="Remarks" SortExpression="remarks" >
              <ControlStyle CssClass="form-control" />
          </asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="PartyId" HeaderText="PartyId" SortExpression="PartyId" Visible="False" />
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action"   ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="id">
              <EditItemTemplate>
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                  &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
              </EditItemTemplate>
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                  &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Here is row data bound event where I tried to perform show and hide column

```
protected void grdview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        if (!admin())
           e.Row.Cells[5].Visible = false;
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) {
        if(!admin()) 
           e.Row.Cells[6].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to hide column than why need to check rowtype?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use of Gridview prerender event as follow.

```
    protected void grdview_RowDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!admin())
        {
           grdview.Columns[5].Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
           //do something
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Nope Its Not working 
protected void grdview_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grdview.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    }